# Using v-on:change to pass specific object element to a function using Vue and Vuetify

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuetify.js

An API call is made to get the list of categories which are delivered in this format:

```
[
  { _id: '5e3339f2dc7b240ffb1f0544', type: 'book', __v: 0 },
  { _id: '5e333d76dc7b240ffb1f0548', type: 'hat', __v: 0 }
]
```

The list of categories populate a dropdown list and 'type' is used for the dropdown text.

```
  <v-card>
    <v-form
      ref="form"
      lazy-validation
    >

      <!-- Category dropdown -->
      <v-select
        :items="categories"
        item-text="type"
        @change="onSelectedCategory"
        label="Category"
        required
        :error-messages="categoryErrors"
        @input="$v.categoryID.$touch()"
        @blur="$v.categoryID.$touch()"
      ></v-select>

    </v-form>
  </v-card>
```

I am using the v-on:change/@change Vue event listener to pass the selected category to the 'onSelectedCategory' function but can seemingly only pass in the field that is being used to display the dropdown text (via item-text="type"). I need to pass in the '_id' field to the function while keeping the 'type' field as the drop down text.

The onSelectedCategory() function prints 'book' for example to the console. I need '5e3339f2dc7b240ffb1f0544'.

```
onSelectedCategory(event) {
  console.log(event);
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `item-value="_id"` to your template.

It should look like this:

```
  <v-select
    :items="categories"
    item-text="type"
    item-value="_id"
    @change="onSelectedCategory"
    label="Category"
    required
    :error-messages="categoryErrors"
    @input="$v.categoryID.$touch()"
    @blur="$v.categoryID.$touch()"
  ></v-select>
```

See [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuetify-v-counter-7tbkmm) a live demo.